# Get activedirectory from samba4

Tags: excel, vba, active-directory, samba

I using LDAP script to get AD info

```
Function getAD()
    UserName = Environ("USERNAME")
 
    Set RootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    Base = "<LDAP://" & RootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ">"
    'filter on user objects with the given account name
    fltr = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)" & "(sAMAccountName=" & UserName & "))"
    'add other attributes according to your requirements
    attr = "account"
    scope = "subtree"
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cmd.activeconnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = Base & ";" & fltr & ";" & attr & ";" & scope
    
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    Do Until rs.EOF
       ' getAD = rs.Fields("distinguishedName").Value

      rs.movenext
    Loop
    rs.Close
   
    conn.Close
End Function
```

But how to get AD info from samba4 domain controller?

Comment: Please check this link it may help you : https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
Set RootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
Base = "<LDAP://" & RootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ">"
```

Tells it to connect to the domain that the current computer is joined to and get the distinguished name of the domain. But that only works if the computer is joined to the domain you want.

If you want to connect to any other domain controller, then you can specify the domain name in the `LDAP://` path:

```
Base = "<LDAP://example.com>"
```

Or an IP, if that's all you have:

```
Base = "<LDAP://10.0.0.1>"
```

Comment: Then don't use RootDSE. Connect directly to LDAP://10.1.1.5

Comment: I tryed it not working

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin You tried using `Base = "<LDAP://10.1.1.5>"`? What was the error message?

Comment: same error imgur.com/218O3z4

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin That sounds like a network issue then. Open a PowerShell window and try `Test-NetConnection 10.1.1.5 -Port 389` - if that fails, then you will need to figure that out first.

Comment: ComputerName     : 10.1.1.5
RemoteAddress    : 10.1.1.5
RemotePort       : 389
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 4
SourceAddress    : 10.0.11.10
TcpTestSucceeded : True

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin That's good. But your screenshot still shows you using `GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")`. Don't use that. Delete that line and for the next line just use `Base = "<LDAP://10.1.1.5>"`

Comment: then i got error on Set RootDse https://pasteboard.co/IJ7gJY62pMS4.png , also i changed IP adress of samba4 but same

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin No, that's not going to work. Don't use RootDSE at all. Delete the `Set RootDSE ...` line and just use `Base = "<LDAP://10.1.1.5>"`

Answer (score -1):

**Samba** is a free Open-Source software which provides a standard interoperability between **Windows OS** and **Linux/Unix** Operating Systems.

You can refer this [link](https://www.tecmint.com/install-samba4-active-directory-ubuntu/) for **Setting Up Samba4 Active Directory Domain Controller**, which covers following topics for **Ubuntu**, **CentOS**, and **Windows**:

> **Note**: Starting from version 4.0, Samba can run as an Active Directory (AD) domain controller (DC). If you are installing Samba in
> a production environment, it is recommended to run two or more DCs for
> failover reasons.